# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: angular

I have below method to store my data which is returning "Success" as response.
I am successfully stored the data in database however still getting "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0” Error" error. Below is my mode.

```
create(resource)
{  
  return this.http.post(this.url + 'saveRegistration.do',resource)
  .pipe(map((response:any)=>JSON.parse(response)),
   catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

I have also tried by modifying this method to

```
create(resource)
    {  
      return this.http.post(this.url + 'saveRegistration.do',resource)
      .pipe(map((response:any)=>JSON.stringify(response)),
       catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

and have tried below as well

```
create(resource)
        {  
          return this.http.post(this.url + 'saveRegistration.do',resource)
          .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
        }
```

and below as well

```
create(resource)
        {  
          return this.http.post(this.url + 'saveRegistration.do',resource)
          .pipe(map((response:any)=>response.text()),
           catchError(this.handleError));
        }
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: You are getting this error as you are tried to parse a JSON into JSON again.

Comment: can you share the JSON data which you receive from your backend?

Comment: Since angular 4, parsing the response is no longer needed, httpclient does it for you.Just remove the map and you should be good.

Comment: @Qellson, I've already tried by removing map if you see above I've written that code as well. But still it's not working for me getting error.

Comment: @BearNithi, I am getting string "SUCCESS" from response.

Comment: If you receiving a "text" (not a json) use {responseType: 'text'}, see https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for your help. It's working for me now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get full response in HttpPost you can write like this

```
 return this.httpClient.post<User>(`${this.API_URL}`, resource, {
    observe: 'response'
 });
```

Also no need to parse to JSON because Angular return JSON by default